# django shuffle query set and remember the pattern of shuffling

Tags: python, django

I have a code that displays questions from the database in random order. But I would like shuffling the questions only once per session (if user refreshes the page/url he should get the same questions as earlier). The code that i have used is

```
def platform(request,e,slug):
    tdetail=get_object_or_404(test_detail,test_id=article)

    ques=list(sorted(Upload.objects.filter(unique_id=tdetail), key=lambda x: random.random()))
    return render(request, 'articles/platform.html',{'ques':ques})
```

the **ques** variable takes all the questions in a list  and then they are accessed at template.....but when the user refreshes the page the questions reshuffle... How should I do ?

Comment: how do you want to understand is user refresh page or first open it?

Comment: You're looking for sessions : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: yeah i think if user access the method for first time i'll create a field in model that will get increment if the method was accessed by user....

Comment: so for next time it'll check if the increment is greater than 1 that means user has already accessed the method...now the problem is how can i restore that order of questions